# Python code to split my excel column value based on delimiter & write 1st split value to same column and 2nd to new column created next to that

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, csv, xlrd

In my excel sheet I have data of below kind...

```
sys_id                  Domain location  tax_amount             tp_category
  8746                              BLR       60000     link:IT,value:63746
  2864   link:EFT,value:874887      HYD       50000                     
  3624  link:Cred,value:897076      CHN       55000                     
  7354                              BLR       60000  link:sales,value:83746
```

I want output in my excel in below format...

```
sys_id Domain_link Domain_value  location . tp_category_link tp_category_value
  8746                               BLR  .              IT              63746
  2864         EFT       874887      HYD  .                      
  3624        Cred       897076      CHN  .                      
  7354                               BLR  .           sales              83746
```

please help me with method or logic I should follow to have data in above format.
I have a huge amount of data and this I need to compare with other excel which is of Target data.

Comment: Please, post also what you've tried so far and the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`, assuming that your input file is called `b1.xlsx`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

VALUE_LINK_REGEX = re.compile('^.*link:(.*),value:(.*)$')

df = pd.read_excel('b1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
cols_to_drop = []
for col in filter(lambda c: is_string_dtype(df[c]), df.columns):
    m = df[col].map(lambda x: None if pd.isna(x) else VALUE_LINK_REGEX.match(x))
    # skip columns with strings different from the expected format
    if m.notna().sum() == 0:
        continue

    cols_to_drop.append(col)
    df[f'{col}_link'] = m.map(lambda x: None if x is None else x.groups()[0])
    df[f'{col}_value'] = m.map(lambda x: None if x is None else x.groups()[1])

df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop, inplace=True)
df.to_excel('b2.xlsx', index=False, engine='openpyxl')
```

This is the resulting `df`:

```sh
   sys_id  location  tax_amount Domain_link Domain_value tp_category_link  \
0     8746      BLR       60000        None         None               IT   
1     2864      HYD       50000         EFT       874887             None   
2     3624      CHN       55000        Cred       897076             None   
3     7354      BLR       60000        None         None            sales   

  tp_category_value  
0             63746  
1              None  
2              None  
3             83746
```

And this is `b2.xlsx`:
[image]

Comment: In the code you used columns Domain and tp_category. but i need generic code which suits for all columns which are having data like "link" and "value". because I have total of 140+ columns and row size of around 4000+. I will try to post more details on this, please go through and plz help me out. Thanks once again.